# Xamarin Forms Android Toolbar missing after migration to Flyout and AppCompat

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

First of all this post is related to that post: [Xamarin Forms Android Error inflating class MaterialCalendarGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70386380/xamarin-forms-android-error-inflating-class-materialcalendargridview)

Before I post any code: The Flyout configuration of Xamarin Forms is correct! If I set `IsPresented = true;` in my flyoutpage the flyout menu is displayed correctly, the only problem I have is, that the top toolbar and the hamburger menu icon is missing completely on Android.

Here is the definition of my `MainActivity.cs`:

```
[Activity(ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView},
        DataScheme = "https",
        DataHost =  "myapp.com",
        AutoVerify = true,
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable})]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        DataScheme = "http",
        DataHost = "myapp.com",
        AutoVerify = true,
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]

    public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity, Android.Gms.Tasks.IOnSuccessListener
    {
    ....
```

Here is my `style.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ec1a23</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#dd2c00</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff3d00</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

As seen mentioned as a solution in the related post, I´m not able to create a `toolbar.xml` file, because my app would crash at the startup. Regarding the `AppCompat` and `Flyout` documentation, it is not necessary at all.

I really don´t know what is the problem here.

Comment: Isn't the problem that you removed stuff needed by the toolbar? Seems to me that your previous question needs to be resolved in a way that doesn't remove toolbar-related Android xml lines. Then this question becomes moot. And probably should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue myself, the fix for me was there was a custom renderer:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer))]
```

This was originally added to fix [Remove icon/logo from action bar on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606294/remove-icon-logo-from-action-bar-on-android) and since it isn't required any more I was able to simply remove the custom renderer, and the toolbar displayed as it should.